# WPF tool for charts, diagrams, graphs

Tags: wpf, charts, diagram

I'm looking for a very simple wpf diagram toolset that would allow me to create simple charts based on data from the database. I need a simple solution - I have seen many that were too advanced, allowing the programmer to create UML diagrams, complicated charts, etc. I want to be able to show simple changes over time with a line - that's it.

I would really appreciate any help on that as well as suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free [WPFToolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) includes a very simple and easy to use charting implementation in its DataVisualization.Toolkit DLL.  It tends to be very good for quick and easy charting of data without having to put much thought into it.  It can be as simple as:

```
<toolkit:Chart>
  <toolkit:LineSeries Title="Series Title"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                      IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"
                      DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" />

  <toolkit:LineSeries ... />
</toolkit:Chart>
```

This assumes your Data is a list of objects each containing a Month and a Value field.  Or you can generate such objects with LINQ:

```
Data =
  from xyz in myData
  select new { Month = xyz.ComputeMonth(), Value = xyz.Count };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ray Burns. I will see if I can use that.

Answer (score 4):

I just came along this one and it seems to be quite exactly what I've been searching for for some time now. Since I didn't find what I was looking for on stackoverflow, I just wanted to let you know:

http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The [WPF Toolkit](https://web.archive.org/web/20180111120841/http://wpf.codeplex.com:80/releases/view/40535) has standard classic charts; [Delay's blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/nobody-likes-a-show-off-todays-datavisualizationdemos-release-includes-new-demos-showing-off-stacked-series-behavior) has a few tutorials/demos on what you can do with them, and how to use them. Would that be sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: I will check it out but the examples shown on the website you mentioned looks promising. I just hope it is easy to use and integrate. Thanks a lot for fast response.